# "message": "Invalid login", "code": 401 for @feathersjs/authentication-local in windows while not in linux or mac

Tags: node.js, windows, feathers-authentication

When I pulled working code of my project which was working fine in Mac, was giving me this error when authenticating in windows

Error

```
{
"name": "NotAuthenticated",
"message": "Invalid login",
"code": 401,
"className": "not-authenticated",
"errors": {}
```

}

post request

```
{

    "strategy": "local",
      "username": "demo",
      "password": "demo"

}
```

**default.json**

```
 "authentication": {
    "entity": "user",
    "service": "users",
    "secret": "2wVrC38R9sUb6Cjhuhoir3oate0=",
    "authStrategies": [
      "jwt",
      "local"
    ],
    "jwtOptions": {
      "header": {
        "type": "access"
      },
      "audience": "https://yourdomain.com",
      "issuer": "feathers",
      "algorithm": "HS256",
      "expiresIn": "1d"
    },
    "local": {
      "usernameField": "username",
      "passwordField": "password"
    }
```

},

So strategy local was not at all working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From documentation [feathers doc](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/local.html#configuration)

"Important: If you want to set the value of usernameField to username in your configuration file under Windows, the value has to be escaped as *\\username* (otherwise the username environment variable will be used)"

thus the code change requires in default.json is

```
  "local": {
  "usernameField": "\\username",
  "passwordField": "password"
   }
```